# Perform a find/match with javascript, ignoring special language characters (accents, for example)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

With a stripos function in javascript, such as:

```
function stripos (f_haystack, f_needle, f_offset) {
  var haystack = (f_haystack + '').toLowerCase();
  var needle = (f_needle + '').toLowerCase();
  var index = 0;

  if ((index = haystack.indexOf(needle, f_offset)) !== -1) {
    return index;
  }
  return false;
}
```

How would I use/recode this function so that it matches special characters?

As if:

```
var haystack = 'Le créme';
var needle   = 'reme';
// ^ these two should match (anything other than false)
```

Comment: create an array that associates special characters to normal charaters, then when doing your match, replace special characters with their non-special equivalents. An example can be found here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#folding

Comment: The answer is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript but please be sure to scroll down because the accepted answer isn't current. My answer is 3rd I believe and should be preferred.

Answer (score 10):

you can clean the strings before the search

```
String.prototype.removeAccents = function(){
 return this
         .replace(/[áàãâä]/gi,"a")
         .replace(/[éè¨ê]/gi,"e")
         .replace(/[íìïî]/gi,"i")
         .replace(/[óòöôõ]/gi,"o")
         .replace(/[úùüû]/gi, "u")
         .replace(/[ç]/gi, "c")
         .replace(/[ñ]/gi, "n")
         .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g," ");
}
```

use:

```
function stripos (f_haystack, f_needle, f_offset) {
  var haystack = (f_haystack + '').toLowerCase().removeAccents();
  var needle = (f_needle + '').toLowerCase().removeAccents();
  var index = 0;

  if ((index = haystack.indexOf(needle, f_offset)) !== -1) {
    return index;
  }
  return false;
}
```