# jQuery Multiple Strings Case and Accent Insensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery

My first post on here. I have a function on a website whereby a randomly generated French phrase is displayed, challenging the reader to translate it into English in a text box. On clicking on a button, the text entered is compared to all the possible answers (there are multiple correct translations for a given phrase). I've looked around for answers on this but nothing seems to suit my situation.

Here's the jQuery:

```
var correctAnswer = function(){$('#correctmessage').show('fast');$('#errormessage').hide('fast');}
var wrongAnswer = function(){$('#errormessage').show('fast');$('#correctmessage').hide('fast');}

$('#1').find('button').on('click', function(){
    var text = $(this).parent().find('.translatefield').val();
    var compareText = "I went to the cinema";
    var compareText2 = "I have been to the cinema";
    if (text == compareText || text == compareText2) {
        correctAnswer();
    }
    else {
        wrongAnswer(); 
    }
});
```

So I wondered if I can put the 'compare' variables into one variable i.e. 'I went to the cinema OR I have been to the cinema OR etc etc' within one variable for tidiness. But mainly I need to know how I can call that variable within the if so that it also accepts the answer without accented characters and regardless of upper or lower case... I hope this is clear! Thanks for any help you can give, this has been irritating me for a while!

Comment: You could put the phrases in an array.
`var compareText = ['I went to the cinema','I have been to the cinema']`
Then you could use the array .some() method to test.

Comment: Most likely easiest solution is to replace everything to its equivalent first, eg replace e-accent with e / all uppercase to lowercase, then you only need to check for 'e'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Mark Holland, use arrays for the compare phrases.

If you are using jQuery anyway, you could use `jQuery.inArray()`.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

var compareText = ['i went to the cinema','i have been to the cinema'];

```
if ($.inArray(text.toLowerCase(), compareText)) {
   ... do stuff
}
```

To ignore the accents, use a solution like this:

```
String.prototype.removeAccents = function(){
 return this
         .replace(/[áàãâä]/gi,"a")
         .replace(/[éè¨ê]/gi,"e")
         .replace(/[íìïî]/gi,"i")
         .replace(/[óòöôõ]/gi,"o")
         .replace(/[úùüû]/gi, "u")
         .replace(/[ç]/gi, "c")
         .replace(/[ñ]/gi, "n")
         .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g," ");
}
```

Credits to Luan Castro
[Perform a find/match with javascript, ignoring special language characters (accents, for example)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236208/perform-a-find-match-with-javascript-ignoring-special-language-characters-acce)

Comment: Hi kernelmaster, thanks a lot for the help. I got the arrays working (wouldn't work with ($.inArray, but it works with jQuery.inArray - any idea why that is? Probably something obvious I'm missing). The accent character removal worked great too - thank you for linking me to Castro's solution.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by Mark Holland, arrays would answer your first question.

[JS arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

To ignore accents, a quick search gave me this answer:

[Replace accents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236208/perform-a-find-match-with-javascript-ignoring-special-language-characters-acce)

And to ignore lower/uppercase, a quick search gave me this answer.

[Ignore case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/javascript-case-insensitive-string-comparison)

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the strings into one array and iterate this array to compare with the answer?